# Copy merged cell and paste in new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that will paste the merged cell into a new merged cell in another worksheet but it returns error.

the main problem is, if i set the range into the String type, eg `sRange as String` there are no problem, but if i set it as `Range` then it has no output also it return a error message.

***My code***:

```
Sub cmd_Click()

    Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long, sRange As Range, sCrange As String, cell As Variant


    Set sRange = Sheet2.Range("J10:J500")
    sCrange = "J5:J600"

    For Each cell In sRange
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            Sheet2.Range(sRange).Copy Sheet4.Range(sCrange)
        End If
    Next      

End Sub
```

Can someone help me fix this, Thanks in Advance!

Comment: if you will share a screen-shot of your data in your merged cell, explain what you are trying to achieve exactly (what needs to be copied from the merged cell), we will be able to offer a more reliable and suitable solution

Comment: do you want me to send the excel to you sir? :) for you to see what my problem is? :)

Comment: No, upload the relevant data to your post here

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GTtQqJx_JgprDXo77WaK8wV7l-0hmQdKOiA_PzzBA6I/edit

Comment: Sir, See this Document for you to see my project.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Sheet2.Range(sRange).Copy Sheet4.Range(sCrange)
```

to

```
sRange.Copy Sheet4.Range(sCrange)
```

Try and see ok or not

Comment: Ok sir. I'll do it :)

Comment: `Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long, sRange As Range, sCrange As String, cell As Variant


    Set sRange = Sheet2.Range("J10:J500")
    sCrange = "J5:J600"

    For Each cell In sRange
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            sRange.Copy Sheet4.Range(sCrange)
        End If
    Next`

It does not work also sir, The debug message is, The object is Required.

Comment: sRange.Copy Sheet4.Range(sCrange).cells(i)

Comment: Sir @Lee Li Fong, what is "i" though?

Comment: What i mean is I dont have a variable "i".

Also if i do this one `sRange.Copy Sheet4.Range(sCrange).cells(cell)` the Whole Column even if it is empty was also copied.

Comment: Change to -                                               Cell.Copy Sheet4.Range(sCrange).cells(i) i=i+1

Comment: where do i place that sir?

Answer (score 0):

Your code change: 
Sheet2.Range(sRange).Copy Sheet4.Range(sCrange)

Change to:
Cell.Copy Sheet4.Range(sCrange).Cell(i)
i=i+1

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing the way you're declaring the variables, try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub cmd_Click()

    Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long
    Dim sRange As Range
    Dim sCrange As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set sRange = Sheet2.Range("J10:J500")
    Set sCrange = Sheet4.Range("J5:J600")

    For Each cell In sRange
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            sCrange.Value = sRange
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It doesnt return any values on the other sheet Sir, But then i tried, `sRange.Copy sCrange`, it works but the empty cells are included.